# jQuery HTML parser is removing some tags without a warning, why and how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Here is the thing,

I have a textarea (with ID "input_container") full of HTML code, the simple example is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="www.example.com">the other place</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I parsed it using jQuery, here is my code:

I have all this HTML string into variable named domString like this:

```
domString = $('#input_container').val();
```

To get a parse HTML of everything inside variable **domString**, I had to wrap it with another tag, so I did:

```
dom = "<allhtml>" + domString + "</allhtml>";
```

And got everything inside a jQuery selector to be parsed:

```
dDom = $(dom);
```

After that I checked what's in dDom, so I did

```
alert(dDom.html());
```

That should give me anything inside the  tags, right?

But unfortunately, all I get is:

```
<a href="www.example.com">the other place</a>
```

And all the other tags are mysteriously gone. Can anyone explain this phenomenon and tell me how to really parse all the DOM?

Thank you

Comment: How are you building  `domString`?

Comment: Did you try with alert(dDom.text()); ?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, domString is simply the HTML string written in the textarea

Comment: @andreapier, dDom.text() returns only the text inside the <a> tag ("the other place").

Comment: @user1087787: How are you retrieving the value from the `textarea`? `var domString= /* ? */;`

Comment: @user1087787: Also, if your end goal is really to `alert` the contents of the textarea, why not just `alert(domString)`?

Comment: I suspect this is gonna help but...<a href="www.example.com'>the other place</a> You open with " and end with ' ... Try changing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>`
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

This should work instead:

```
$('<html />').append($('<head />')).append($('<body />').append($('<a href="www.example.com">the other place</a>')));
```

This is kind of a weird thing to do, though- you might want to think about other ways to do what you're trying to accomplish, I worry that you might be suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I just wanted to do what I asked, I have ANY HTML in a textarea (it's not my page's HTML or anything constant at all), and I want to parse it using jQuery, the method I used works well for parsing HTML that is not the page itself using jQuery, but it removes some tags (as I mentioned in the original post).

I can't use the trick you showed me since I can never know what's the HTML tags I'm going to have in that textarea...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're using jQuery `load` or an AJAX call.

This will attempt to load the document into your current DOM.  It will get the *contents* of the HEAD and BODY tags via `innerHtml`, but not the tags themselves (including the HTML tag, naturally).

[From the jQuery Load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`,
>   `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

EDIT:
If you are trying to get the full HTML for your page, the same thing applies.  It's going to use the browser's innerHtml function which will behave as described above.  HTML doesn't really exist once the DOM is loaded, so going the opposite direction won't necessarily be 100% correct.

When you load that HTML into the DOM, it'll ignore the tags as they don't actually get loaded at all.  Then when you're retrieving, all that's left is the link (as well as whatever you have in the HEAD, but you don't have anything in there...).

Comment: Downvoted with no comment as to why?  You're kidding, right?  Considering my answer is 100% correct and was initially written when the OP had no context as to HOW he was getting that HTML, I'm amazed.  Bad form.

Comment: I just wanted to do what I asked, I have ANY HTML in a textarea (it's not my page's HTML or anything constant at all), and I want to parse it using jQuery, the method I used works well for parsing HTML that is not the page itself using jQuery, but it removes some tags (as I mentioned in the original post).

Comment: @user1087787 I suggest you familiarize yourself with the conventions and constructive behavior of StackOverflow.  Further, when I answered this question, you had zero mention of a textarea and instead said that you just had the HTML.  Note my first sentence, I had to make an assumption as to the source of the HTML.  You're penalizing me, rather than posting a clarification, for attempting to help.  Voting people down for honest attempts at helping you is a good way to make sure no one helps you in the future.

Comment: I never voted you down, and this is my second/third post in StackOverflow. I'll try my best to post more relevant and helpful data along my questions in the future.

Comment: @user1087787 Ah, I just assumed because you responded that you were the one that voted me down.