# Parse and handle DOM that came as a string input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

Here is the thing,

I have a textarea (with ID "input_container") full of HTML code, the simple example is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="www.example.com">the other place</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I parse it and use it in jQuery as a legitimate DOM? 
For example, to do

```
$(varWithDom).find(...)
```

with that DOM?

**What I already tried**

I tried to parse it using jQuery but a funny thing happened - jQuery removed the DOCTYPE and all of the HEAD, and left me with nothing but

```
        <a href="www.example.com">the other place</a>
```

My original method is here: [jQuery HTML parser is removing some tags without a warning, why and how to prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618205/jquery-html-parser-is-removing-some-tags-without-a-warning-why-and-how-to-preve)

I never found a solution yet. Any ideas? might this be a bug on jQuery or what?

Comment: Which parts do you actually care about? Why does it matter that jQuery strips out everything but the contents of `<body>`? As per the jQuery documentation that [evan quoted in answering your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8618609/139010), this isn't a jQuery bug - **it's the browser's built-in `.innerHTML` implementation** that's dropping tags.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: It'll matter because if the element queried is a child of `body`, and the `body` is stripped away, then `.find()` won't be able to locate it. `.filter()` would be needed instead.

Comment: In that case just wrap the whole thing up in a `<div>` as [@am not i am suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8625939/139010).

Comment: Why do you need the elements from the HEAD? Why do you need the DOCTYPE? What is your intention here?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the entire content as elements, you might try using an `iframe`.

```js
 // create and append new iframe
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

  // set its innerHTML
iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML = varWithDOM;

  // grab the `window`
var win = iframe.contentWindow;

  // remove the iframe
document.documentElement.removeChild(iframe);
```

Demo that grabs the `head`: http://jsfiddle.net/K6tR2/

---

***original answer***

It isn't so much jQuery removing it as it is the browser. This behavior will vary in different browsers.

One thing you might try would be to place the entire thing in a `<div>`, so that becomes your context...

```js
$('<div>' + varWithDom + '</div>').find(...)
```

Now it won't really matter what is stripped away (unless you actually needed something in the `<head>`), because it will all be descendant of the outer `div`.

If you didn't want that, then you'd need to do your query twice, once with `.find()`, and once with `.filter()`...

```js
var els = $( varWithDom );
var links = els.find( 'a[href]' ).add( els.filter( 'a[href]' ) );
```

Comment: I tried that :( it didn't work. jQuery is still stripping the <head> and the doctype, I need to HTML as a whole...

The funny thing is, when I try to approach to jQuery selectors in the page I succeed - $('head') works fine, so why not with an external DOM?

Comment: @user1087787: I updated with a solution that uses an `iframe`. Give that a shot.

Comment: Just tested it in IE9 and FF - Unfortunately they both got problems parsing it, FF doesn't find tags and IE is giving me this error:

Message: Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined
Line: 832
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/form


Message: Unable to get value of the property 'find': object is null or undefined
Line: 4
Char: 21213
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: I also ran your script from jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/K6tR2/) and it returns errors in IE9 and FF... any suggestions?